# MongoDB shell: how to remove all collections except list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to remove all collections except a list.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(n){db[n].remove({})});
```

will remove all collections.

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(collection){return! /^((keepthisone)|(andthisone)|(alsokeepthisone))$/.test(collection)});
```

will list all the collections, except the ones I want to keep.

How do I combine the two?

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(collection){return! /^((keepthisone)|(andthisone)|(alsokeepthisone))$/.test(collection)}).forEach(function(n){db[n].remove({})});
```

Does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `map` then `drop` on items :

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(collection) {
    return !/^((keepthisone)|(andthisone)|(alsokeepthisone))$/.test(collection);
}).map(function(n){
    return db.getCollection(n);
}).forEach(function(collection){
    collection.drop();
});
```

Comment: `db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(n){return! /^((keepthisone)|(andthisone)|(alsokeepthisone))$/.test(n)}).forEach(function(n){db.getCollection(n).drop({});});` Worked for me also.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this:

```
db.getSiblingDB('test').getCollectionNames().filter( 
   collection => !['keepthisone', 'andthisone', 'alsokeepthisone'].includes(collection)
).forEach( collection => {
    db.getSiblingDB('test').getCollection(collection).drop();
});
```

You should use `getSiblingDB(...)` for security reasons. You never know if the user executed stupid command like `use admin` before running yours. The result would be rather bad.